# Printing server report without preview showing up zoomed report

Tags: reporting-services, printing

I'm trying to print a server report without preview using C#. The report is printing fine in WidowsXP but it's printing in zoomed view in Windows 7 and Windows 10. Below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

namespace Dahlawi.ManPower.Recruiting.Forms
{
public partial class FrmReportViewer1 : Form
{
    List<Metafile> m_ReportPages = new List<Metafile>();
    int m_ReportPageIndex = 0;

    public FrmReportViewer1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument objPrintDoc = new PrintDocument();

        objPrintDoc.PrintPage += PrintPageHandler;

        PrintDialog objPrintDiag = new PrintDialog();
        objPrintDiag.Document = objPrintDoc;

        DialogResult objDiagResult = default(DialogResult);
        objDiagResult = objPrintDiag.ShowDialog();

        if (objDiagResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            objPrintDoc.PrinterSettings = objPrintDiag.PrinterSettings;

            this.m_ReportPages = new List<Metafile>();

            this.m_ReportPageIndex = 0;

            this.reportViewer.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;
            this.reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("USER", "PASSWORD", "DOMAIN");

            this.reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://SERVER/ReportServer");
            this.reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/DMR/Candidate_Information";

            ReportParameter[] reportParameters = new ReportParameter[] { new ReportParameter("CandidateId", "16744") };
            reportParameters[0].Visible = false;
            this.reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
            this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();

            string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" + "<OutputFormat>emf</OutputFormat>" + "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" + "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" + "  <MarginTop>0.2in</MarginTop>" + "  <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>" + "  <MarginRight>0.5in</MarginRight>" + "  <MarginBottom>0.2in</MarginBottom>" + "</DeviceInfo>";

            Warning[] objWarnings = null;
            string[] sStreamIDs = null;
            string sMimeType = "";
            string sEncoding = "";
            string sFilenameExtension = "";

            byte[] renderedPage = null;

            renderedPage = this.reportViewer.ServerReport.Render("Image", deviceInfo, out sMimeType, out sEncoding, out sFilenameExtension, out sStreamIDs, out objWarnings);
            this.m_ReportPages.Add(new Metafile(new MemoryStream(renderedPage)));

            foreach (string sStreamId in sStreamIDs)
            {
                renderedPage = this.reportViewer.ServerReport.RenderStream("Image", sStreamId, deviceInfo, out sMimeType, out sEncoding);
                this.m_ReportPages.Add(new Metafile(new MemoryStream(renderedPage)));
            }

            objPrintDoc.Print();

            objPrintDoc = null;
        }
    }

    private void PrintPageHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.m_ReportPageIndex < this.m_ReportPages.Count)
        {
            Metafile imgPage = this.m_ReportPages[this.m_ReportPageIndex];

            this.m_ReportPageIndex += 1;

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgPage, 0, 0, imgPage.Width, imgPage.Height);

            e.HasMorePages = this.m_ReportPageIndex < this.m_ReportPages.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I print the report using above code in WindowsXP it prints like this [Proper Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHCaF.png)

But when I run the same code in Windows 7 or Windows 10 it prints like this [Zoomed Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ztPu.png)

Please help me run this code on Windows 7 / Windows 10. I can provide more details if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue and it's the "emf" output format which is causing the problem on Windows 7 and Windows 10 but working fine on Windows XP / Windows 2003. I changed the output format in "deviceInfo" string from "emf"  to "jpg" (other formats e.g. "png", "jpeg", "bmp" also work fine) and then I changed the type of "m_ReportPages" list object from "Metafile" to "Image" and got the issue resolved.